# Ubuntu 16.10 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 16.10, downgrade

Hi guys I have a laptop dual-booted with Ubuntu 16.10 and Windows 7. So I was wondering if I could downgrade back to 16.04 LTS and btw I installed 16.04 then upgraded to 16.10. I really want to go back to 16.04 because a lot of software I want hasn't been released for 16.10 "Yakkety"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way of doing a "rollback" to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
However you could always just backup, get the 16.04 LTS installation files and clean install.

Comment: How could I do that? Could you supply me with a full text tutorial since I am a newbie to all this:) it would be very much appreciated, and remember I have Windows 7 aswell:)

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend How did you install Ubuntu in the first place? Boot into Windows, format the Ubuntu partition, and then fill out/extend the Windows partition (you can do this from the disk partitioner in Windows). Then, create a Ubuntu LiveUSB, boot it, and install alongside Windows. There is plenty of documentation and no need to create yet another guide for how to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: @PatrickNegus I had installed Ubuntu 16.04 first then upgraded to 16.10 and then installed Windows 7 on a different partition. And, lets continue this chat in e-mail? E-mail me - abdulnaiem1@gmail.com, and ill send you screenshot of Gparted and tell you which is which.